# A message "Sorry! the application(name..) has stopepd unexpectedly , please try again

Tags: android

I am an Android beginner, and i have downloaded SDK 4.4.2 since few days.

I started with an application consisting of two buttons and a text field where one button increments the number in the text field and the other button decrements the number . I run this app in 2 different PCs , it worked fine with one of them , but in my laptop when i run it, i keep getting the above message whenever i use the statement:

```
disp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt);
```

or

```
disp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
```

(all id's and variables are declared correctly and there are no errors)

what can i do to fix this problem in my laptop ? please help

LogCat :

01-22 23:01:49.483: D/AndroidRuntime(279): Shutting down VM
01-22 23:01:49.483: W/dalvikvm(279): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-22 23:01:49.533: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  ... 11 more
01-22 23:01:58.465: I/Process(279): Sending signal. PID: 279 SIG: 9
01-22 23:11:08.554: D/AndroidRuntime(309): Shutting down VM
01-22 23:11:08.554: W/dalvikvm(309): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-22 23:11:08.573: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  ... 11 more
01-22 23:12:25.532: D/AndroidRuntime(372): Shutting down VM
01-22 23:12:25.573: W/dalvikvm(372): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-22 23:12:25.602: E/AndroidRuntime(372):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 23:36:44.835: D/AndroidRuntime(401): Shutting down VM
01-22 23:36:44.835: W/dalvikvm(401): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-22 23:36:44.863: E/AndroidRuntime(401):  ... 11 more
01-22 23:41:45.003: I/Process(401): Sending signal. PID: 401 SIG: 9
01-22 23:53:18.613: D/AndroidRuntime(423): Shutting down VM
01-22 23:53:18.613: W/dalvikvm(423): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-22 23:53:18.653: E/AndroidRuntime(423):  ... 11 more
01-22 23:53:36.123: I/Process(423): Sending signal. PID: 423 SIG: 9
01-22 23:54:23.742: W/KeyCharacterMap(452): No keyboard for id 0
01-22 23:54:23.742: W/KeyCharacterMap(452): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-22 23:57:06.783: D/AndroidRuntime(479): Shutting down VM
01-22 23:57:06.783: W/dalvikvm(479): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-22 23:57:06.813: E/AndroidRuntime(479):  ... 11 more
01-23 00:02:06.886: I/Process(479): Sending signal. PID: 479 SIG: 9
01-23 00:06:05.613: D/AndroidRuntime(502): Shutting down VM
01-23 00:06:05.613: W/dalvikvm(502): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-23 00:06:05.645: E/AndroidRuntime(502):  ... 11 more
01-23 00:11:05.723: I/Process(502): Sending signal. PID: 502 SIG: 9
01-23 00:30:09.962: D/AndroidRuntime(585): Shutting down VM
01-23 00:30:09.962: W/dalvikvm(585): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-23 00:30:09.982: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  ... 11 more
01-23 00:41:57.103: D/AndroidRuntime(612): Shutting down VM
01-23 00:41:57.103: W/dalvikvm(612): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-23 00:41:57.123: E/AndroidRuntime(612):  ... 11 more
01-23 00:42:01.855: I/Process(612): Sending signal. PID: 612 SIG: 9
01-23 00:46:03.922: D/AndroidRuntime(641): Shutting down VM
01-23 00:46:03.922: W/dalvikvm(641): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-23 00:46:03.942: E/AndroidRuntime(641):  ... 11 more
01-23 00:46:12.433: I/Process(641): Sending signal. PID: 641 SIG: 9
01-23 00:48:05.382: D/AndroidRuntime(669): Shutting down VM
01-23 00:48:05.382: W/dalvikvm(669): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-23 00:48:05.412: E/AndroidRuntime(669):  ... 11 more
01-23 00:48:09.752: I/Process(669): Sending signal. PID: 669 SIG: 9
01-23 00:49:05.772: D/AndroidRuntime(697): Shutting down VM
01-23 00:49:05.772: W/dalvikvm(697): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-23 00:49:05.812: E/AndroidRuntime(697):  ... 11 more
01-23 00:51:25.972: D/AndroidRuntime(740): Shutting down VM
01-23 00:51:25.972: W/dalvikvm(740): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-23 00:51:26.002: E/AndroidRuntime(740):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    ... 11 more

Comment: Your PC should not affect the emulating Android device (I assume that's what you mean by 2 different PCs). I recommned learning how to debug and log the error more carefully with logcat

Comment: Please post the logcat output for the crash. I take it that you are running the app on emulators on these various environments. Is the laptop environment properly configured?

Comment: could you post your logcat till see the cause of error

Comment: if you are sure your ids are correct then try "clean" the project. Clean project option is under Project menu.

Comment: i tried clean but it didnt work , i have posted LogCat results

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening because you are executing this code before your activity is created.

Make sure you put this code at the end of your `onCreate()` method, not at the start.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout
com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
```

The error is there, you have a Casting problem with a RelativeLayout object. My guess is that it is a `findViewById` with the wrong ´id` or wrong ´casting´. I can't help you more since you didn't provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

Also I wold recomend you to debug your app in a mobile device... I mean in your Android phone... it takes a lot of work off from your PC and RAM and also you will see all the debug information in the logcat...

regards...!!